# What is meaning of "?" in tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am new to tensorflow and I want to create

```
Tensor("batch:0",shape=(?, 299, 299, 3), dtype=float32)
```

- How can I can create This?
- What is the meaning of "?" in it.

Thanks

Comment: @ jonrsharpe Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

It means that this dimension is not fixed in the graph and it can vary between different run calls.

Comment: Usually used as placeholder for batch size